# Wordpress Gallery Shortcode Pregreplace

Tags: wordpress, gallery, shortcode

Basically I need to remove the gallery shortcode from the Wordpress content, I'm using

```
echo preg_replace('/\[gallery ids=[^\]]+\]/', '',  get_the_content() );
```

It is removing the gallery shortcode successfully, but also the paragraph tags which I need to keep. The idea is that I want to output everything in the content except the gallery.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Wordpress strip_shortcode function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes).

Look at the example in the Codex. 
You can create a filter that strips shortcodes:

```
function remove_shortcode_from($content) {
  $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  return $content;
}
```

and call it when you need (in your template):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_shortcode_from');
the_content();
remove_filter('the_content', 'remove_shortcode_from')
```

**EDIT 1**

Another way to get that (and answering you comment) you can use [Wordpress apply_filters function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) in the content after remove the undesirables shortcodes.

```
//within loop
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace('/\[gallery ids=[^\]]+\]/', '',  $content );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content );
echo $content;
```

But I would not recommend to you to do that. I think forcing your site to modify the content of a post could make that hard to understanding. Maybe you should work with [Wordpress Excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) and avoid any problem.

[A link that helped me](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/apply-filters-to-get_the_content)

Comment: It's a nice solution and works well for what I'm trying to achieve, but stripping all shortcodes might become troublesome with a more complex theme.

Answer (score 0):

to remove a shortcode or a particular list of shortcode you can use this code.

```
global $remove_shortcode;
/**
* Strips and Removes shortcode if exists
* @global int $remove_shortcode
* @param type $shortcodes comma seprated string, array of shortcodes
* @return content || excerpt
*/
function dot1_strip_shortcode( $shortcodes ){
  global $remove_shortcode;
  if(empty($shortcodes)) return;

  if(!is_array($shortcodes)){
    $shortcodes = explode(',', $shortcodes);
  }
  foreach( $shortcodes as $shortcode ){
    $shortcode = trim($shortcode);
    if( shortcode_exists($shortcode) ){
        remove_shortcode($shortcode);
    }
    $remove_shortcode[$shortcode] = 1;
  }
  add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'strip_shortcode' );
  add_filter( 'the_content', 'strip_shortcode' );    
}
function strip_shortcode( $content) {
  global $shortcode_tags, $remove_shortcode;

  $stack = $shortcode_tags;
  $shortcode_tags = $remove_shortcode;
  $content = strip_shortcodes($content);

  $shortcode_tags = $stack;
  return $content;
}
dot1_strip_shortcode( 'gallery' );
```

Accepts single, comma seprated shortcode string or array of shortcodes.